# IllegalArgumentException when trying to create @Query in Spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring

I try to get a field with my query ( status - just a simple enum ).

```
@Query("SELECT Order.status from Order o WHERE o.id = :id")
Status getStatusById (@Param(value = "id")  long id);
```

This is the exception I get right on the start **before this query is invoked**.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read field "value" because "s1" is null
```

Important Part of my order entity

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "orders")
@ToString
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Status status;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solved my problem

```
@Query("SELECT o.status FROM Order o WHERE o.id=:id")
```

Comment: thanks for sharing this response, this also solved the same error message I had.